# Is there a way to find consumer group in DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a project that uses a DLQ approach where on any exception in a `@KafkaListener`, the error will be send to a topic with the structure `error-<topic>-<consumergroup>`. When we want to manually retry a kafka message from this DLQ, we will produce it to a topic with similar structure `retry-<topic>-<consumergroup>`. So for example if we would have a main topic `foo`, consumed by the consumer group `bar`, we would have the topics: `foo`, `error-foo-bar` and `retry-foo-bar`.

This way, we can retry a message for a specific consumer group. The message handler reads from both the main topic, and the retry topic.

Since we have more than one listener in the project that all use the same container, we have put the topics (main, error and retry) in application properties and configured the `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` to find the corresponding DLQ (note, this is Kotlin):

```
val recoverer = DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template) { record, _ ->
    val dlq = kafkaProperties.topics.values.firstOrNull { it.main == record.topic() || it.retry == record.topic() }!!.dlq

    return@DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer TopicPartition(dlq, -1)
}
```

This all works fine. However now I'd like to add another `@KafkaListener` that listens on the **same topic** as another listener. Therefore I need to give this listener a separate consumer group.

However, if I'd use the same logic for finding the corresponding DLQ topic as above, one of the two listeners will use the other one's DLQ, as it is not looking at the consumer group here.

So my question is: in Spring Kafka, is there any way to find in which **consumer group** (aka `groupId`) the error occured? I've looked at both the documentation and source code but couldn't find it myself. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group.id` for the consumer is available by calling `KafkaUtils.getGroupId()` (it is stored in a `ThreadLocal` when the container thread starts up).

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the answer Are there any alternatives or is this the preferred solution? Seems that I'll have to figure out if I can use this inside `DLPR` configuration I have now (currently living in a Bean definition).

Comment: You don't need to "figure out if I can use this". The `DLPR` is always called on the consumer thread so it is always valid when the destination resolver is called on that thread.